# Want to call Defragment Process in Windows 7 using C#.net Desktop Application

Tags: c#, .net, desktop-application

I want to open the disk defragmenter window in Windows 7 using Visual Studio 2010 C# .Net.

I use this code:

```
Process.Start("dfrgui"); // 'dfrgui' is used to open disk defragment window in Windows 7
```

but the window does not appear.

But in Windows XP I use

```
Process.Start("dfrg.msc");
```

and here the window does appear.

Is there another way to call defragmenter in Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

Use this Command i hope it works on every system

```
ProcessStartInfo pf = new ProcessStartInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "dfrgui.exe"));
pf.Verb = "runas";

Process.Start(pf);
```